# How to get the output value from stored procedure from another stored procedure in a tabular format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with following data which has `itemID` and `Imagepath`(s)

**tableImagePath**

```
ItemID     frontimage                          backimage
---------  ----------------------------------  ---------------------------------
772740509  2011\11\24\1\8014681_5_1_FRONT.tif  2011\11\24\1\8014681_5_1_BACK.tif
772740508  2011\11\24\1\8014680_4_1_FRONT.tif  2011\11\24\1\8014680_4_1_BACK.tif
772740507  2011\11\24\1\8014679_3_1_FRONT.tif  2011\11\24\1\8014679_3_1_BACK.tif
772740506  2011\11\24\1\8014678_2_1_FRONT.tif  2011\11\24\1\8014678_2_1_BACK.tif
772740505  2011\11\24\1\8014677_1_1_FRONT.tif  2011\11\24\1\8014677_1_1_BACK.tif
772740504  2011\11\24\1\8014676_5_1_FRONT.tif  2011\11\24\1\8014676_5_1_BACK.tif
772740503  2011\11\24\1\8014675_4_1_FRONT.tif  2011\11\24\1\8014675_4_1_BACK.tif
772740502  2011\11\24\1\8014674_3_1_FRONT.tif  2011\11\24\1\8014674_3_1_BACK.tif
772740501  2011\11\24\1\8014673_2_1_FRONT.tif  2011\11\24\1\8014673_2_1_BACK.tif
772740500  2011\11\24\1\8014672_1_1_FRONT.tif  2011\11\24\1\8014672_1_1_BACK.tif
```

I have stored procedure which produces an output of an image (from the imagepath above) in base64 encoded.

```
declare @base64image as varchar(max)
exec dbo.prIMGCLR_ReadImage_Base64 '2011\11\24\1\8014681_5_1_FRONT.tif', @base64image out 
select @base64image
```

Which returns the output as given below:

```
SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA....
```

Note: The `dbo.prIMGCLR_ReadImage_Base64` stored procedure is actually locked, I cannot open the source to see what it is inside.
So I have to use this procedure only, I have no other function that returns the value in base64 encoded.

Now if I use this same procedure to get the base64 encoded values for `FrontImage` and `BackImage`, the output should look like this...

**tableImage_Base64Encoded**

```
772740509   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...
772740508   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...
772740507   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...
772740506   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...
772740505   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...
772740504   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...
772740503   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...
772740502   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...
772740501   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...
772740500   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...   SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAKwIAAAIBAwABAAAAAQA+gAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACIAAAAAQAAAMgAAAABAAAA...
```

Could some one please help me out to get this done in good performance way.  Instead of looping through each one to produce the result.
Some times this can go more than 1000 rows of items.  So that time it can take ages to produce the output in a tabular form.
Thanks for taking look in the question and providing me the solution.

Comment: Any chance you could create a function that takes an single input, feeds that into the stored proc and executes, then returns the base64?  Might not do much for performance, but would be easier to call

Answer (score 0):

If you can't convert the proc that produces the base64 string into a scalar-value function, I am afraid there's nothing you can do but iterate through your rows and generate the values one at a time